# Возможно ли убрать кнопку "Закрыть" в консольном приложении?

Tags: c#, консоль

Можно ли как-нибудь убрать крестик(кнопку) закрытия в консольном приложении *C#*?
Или даже отменить закрытие программы при нажатии на эту кнопку?

Comment: Обычное "отключение" не подойдет? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052992/how-can-i-disable-close-button-of-console-window-in-a-visual-studio-console-appl

Comment: @FoggyFinder , Спасибо, подошло! 
Благодарю за данную статью

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Решение этой же проблемы с EN stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6054593/5232946)

Правда оно не "убирает", а делает неактивной.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;
        public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int DeleteMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int nPosition, int wFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DeleteMenu(GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), false), SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: И это прекрасно подойдет! 
Спасибо.

Comment: @Varagian http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.deletemenu тут описаны возможные константы для функции DeleteMenu